# (Library not found for -lswiftCore) inside Xamarin for a native referenced static library project

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I have a static library that is being compiled by xcode (Objective-C + SWIFT). I'm trying to bind it to a Xamarin.iOS project. I have done that before but this several times before but I think the SWIFT part is the new thing this time. At building xamarin gives tens of errors starting with few native libraries not found (for swift) and then missing swift symbols. I think it may be a support problem from xamarin towards swift :/
Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

> MT5209: Error: warning: Auto-Linking library not found for
>   **-lswiftCore**  Native linking
>
> MT5209: Error: warning: Auto-Linking library not found for
>   **-lswiftQuartzCore**  Native linking   MT5209: Error: warning: Auto-Linking library not found for **-lswiftCoreImage**  Native
>   linking
>
> .....

Comment: There is no current official support from Microsoft/Xamarin in binding Swift-based frameworks, for static libs that use Swift libs, you will need to manually include a ref to the swift frameworks that are being used. https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76